# Unable to use esBuild library with multi entry points

Tags: javascript, typescript, esbuild

I have x2 packages - `app` and `my-lib`

`App` is a basic react app using webpack 5 and TS 4.6

`my-lib` is library compiled with esBuild. The goal is to bundle each module within `my-lib` individually so the consuming app can consume as:

```
import { Profile } from 'my-lib/profile'
```

or

```
import { Account } from 'my-lib/account'
```

The main purpose of this is so the consuming app does not need to import the whole bundle, but the smaller modules and helps with tree-shaking.

my-lib:

```
esbuild.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
src
    components
        profile
            profile.tsx
            index.ts
        account
            account.tsx
            index.ts
        ////
        //// more and more 'mini' components
        ////
```

In each of the above index.ts, the contents is:

```
export * from './Profile'; 
// Account...
```

my-lib esbuild.js:

```
import { globPlugin } from 'esbuild-plugin-glob';

esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['src/**/index.ts'],
  outdir: 'dist',
  format: 'esm',
  target: ['es6']
  sourcemap: true,
  plugins: [globPlugin()],
});
```

my-lib package.json

```
name: 'my-lib',
main: 'dist/index.js',
types: 'dist/index.d.ts',
exports: {
    profile: './dist/profile/index.js',
    account: './dist/account/index.js'
}
```

After building the `my-lib`, i see:

```
esbuild.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
dist. // <-- result from build
    profile
        profile.d.ts
        index.d.ts
        index.js
    account
        account.d.ts
        index.d.ts
        index.js

src
    components
        profile
            profile.tsx
            index.ts
        account
            account.tsx
            index.ts
        ////
        //// more and more 'mini' components
        ////
```

`app` package.json:

```
{
    ////
    'dependencies': {
        'my-lib': 'file:my-lib'
    } 
}
```

After running npm install in `app`, i can see `my-lib` is installed in node_modules + the contents looks correct.

However in `app > src > user.tsx` i cannot import from `my-lib`. I have tried:

```
import { Profile } from 'my-lib';    
import { Profile } from 'my-lib/profile';    
import { profile } from 'my-lib';    
import { profile } from 'my-lib/profile';
```

However i am presented with:

```
Unable to find module 'my-lib' or its type definitions.
```

Update - adding

my-lib tsconfig

```
{
  'extends': '../tsconfig.json'
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "lib"
  }
}
```

app tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", es2018, dom, esnext],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    resolveJsonModule: true,
    jsx: 'react',
    isolatedModules: true
  }
}
```

Comment: `main: 'dist/index.js'` doesn't appear to exist in your build results

Comment: Correct, reading the npm/node docs, it suggests to use exports?

Comment: Yeah, those should work, but `import { … } from 'my-lib';` can't be used without such a file.

Comment: Given i have specifiede ntryPoints: ['src/**/index.ts'], as a multi, how would one go about creating a single index in root?